# How to find the number of columns in the bindingsource?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create dynamic table based on the `bindingsource`. My `datasource` is bind with the `bindingsource`. So, How can I know number of columns beforehand while creating a table?

Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `BindingSource.GetItemProperties` method.
For instance, let's assume that the following class represents a single table row (as well as a single `BindingSource` item):

```
public class Item
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Since it has two public properties, so the `BindingSource` will have two columns.

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = list };
```

You can get the number of columns in it as follows:

```
int columnsCount = bindingSource.GetItemProperties(null).Count;  // returns 2
```